# Difference between "man" and a man or the man

Tags: american-english

I watched a [video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfGMYdalClU).
The title of The video is "MAN".

So, I wonder against the title "MAN".

Why only MAN? Ordinary "A MAN" or "THE MAN", right?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. As a first step, I'd strongly suggest you look up the word *man* in a number of good dictionaries, such as Oxford, Merriam-Websters, American Heritage, Collins. You can even go to [OneLook](https://www.onelook.com/) and do a single search and get multiple results. Next, if a reasonably thorough search does not give you an applicable definition, at that point edit your question here and tell us which dictionaries you checked, which definitions you considered and why those definitions didn't work for you. 1) This site requires your own research 2) so that we don't duplicate it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. As Stack Exchange is set up to be a long-term reference repository, question posts (and answer posts) should be self-contained. Links are welcome, but the post itself must quote the relevant parts. In the case of your question, you're asking about a word (man) within a title, but you haven't quoted the title. Please make changes using the [edit] link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video isn't about A man or The man, rather it is about the [species man.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human)

See Merriam's definition B.

> b : the human race : humankind
>
> "the history of man"
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/man

This is fairly common usage in my experience.

Saying "The man" has an entirely different connotation that relates to authority figures, whereas "a man" is commonly used to indicate an individual person.

Comment: I feel a little torn by my reaction to the video.  While dark and mildly terrifying, it was also rather humerous.